# call a method of class instance located inside a python list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have following classes in python:

- `QueryElement` as a root class
- `ElemMatch` and `GT` which inherit from the root.

I have a list in `ElemMatch` class which is supposed to have instances of `QueryElement`.

My problem is in invoking a method called `compute` from the instances inside the list, in `ElemMatch` class(compute method). The type of object inside the list is not identified by Python, and I do not know how to assign a type to the list. I do not have such a problem in Java since I could 'cast' to a type I like, but here I do not know how to solve it.

I appreciate if you could help.

```
class QueryElement(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def addQueryElement(self, queryElement):        
        raise NotImplementedError( "Should have implemented this" )


    @abc.abstractmethod
    def compute(self):      
        raise NotImplementedError( "Should have implemented this" )


class ElemMatch(QueryElement):

    def __init__(self):
        self._queryElements = []

    def addQueryElement(self, queryElement):
        self._queryElements.append(queryElement)

    def compute(self):
        elemMatch = {}
        if len (self._queryElements) > 0:
            elemMatch['e'] = self._queryElements[0].compute()

        return elemMatch    


class GT(QueryElement):

    def __init__(self):
        print 'someThing'

    def addQueryElement(self, queryElement):
        return None

    def compute(self):
        print 'compute GT!' 

class PALLAS(object):
    def foo(self):
        gt = GT()
        elemMatch = ElemMatch()

        elemMatch.addQueryElement(gt)
        elemMatch.compute()

p = PALLAS()
p.foo()
```

Comment: Are you trying to change the type of the object, or call a `compute` function belonging to a different class from the object? Or is your list already made up of `QueryElement` objects and you just want to call `compute`?

Comment: Is there an error being thrown when you use this code?

Comment: @TheSoundDefense : I am not trying to change the type of object. I just make an empty list(in init) and create two methods to populate it and call compute method.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense: I think python does not identify the type since populating the list is another class (PALLAS).

Comment: @IanAuld: It just says that compute is not attribute of queryElements :(

Comment: @user3376020 Python does not need to know the type before attempting to call `compute`. It will just check to see if the object has a `compute` method, and call it if it does. It's not like Java where the type has to be specifically known ahead of time. See the current answer.

Comment: If you're getting an exception, can you include the full stack trace? The code you've shown seems just works when I try it, so if it is not working for you you'll need to elaborate a bit more on what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, the objects, not the names referring to them, are typed. If the object has a `compute` method, you can call it, regardless of what the type of the object is.

A quick example:

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self):
        print "I'm an A"

class B(object):
    def foo(self):
        print "I'm a B"

lst = [A(), A(), B(), A(), B()]
for l in lst:
    l.foo()
```

Each element of `lst` is either an instance of `A` or of `B`. Since both have a method named `foo`, you don't have to know the type of the object referenced by `l` each time through the loop; the lookup of `foo` will find the correct method.

This is commonly referred to as *duck typing*; if `l` looks like a duck and acts like a duck (i.e., if it has a method `foo`), then it is a duck (i.e., then we can call the method `foo`).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It is very useful. In my case, the objects which eventually will be added to the list, are all in the same type, with compute() method. What are possible reasons that python does not identify it?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it's a design decision. Python is often said to have names, not variables. The names can refer to anything: one moment, `x` might refer to an integer, the next, a function, and after that a class. The downside is that you can't catch errors like "`x` doesn't have an attribute `foo`" at compile time, because you won't know for sure what `x` refers to until you actually try to access the `foo` attribute of whatever `x` refers to at the moment.

Comment: Put another way, many of the things you may be used to determining at compile time aren't actually done until run time in Python.